# Raw vs Lookup values in REST API

Tags: rest, api

We are implementing REST API on our project and we can not reach a consensus about a response data.

So we have some "code" entities. These entities contain fields Code (simple alphanumeric identifier) and Description of this code (some describing text). On some pages of current client application we need to show lookup values based on the user settings (e.g. Code - Description or Description - Code). Should REST API return configured values or it should return only raw code values? My opinion is that representation is a client's responsibility.

What do you think?

Comment: Are the descriptions configurable? If so, you will need to return the description as well, as there is no way the client could know it's value *a priori*. If not, well, personally I'd return the description as well, as it will allow you centralized control of it in the future - it's more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

I would return both code and description. If the client do not want to use the description provided by the server, they can simply ignore it.

---

If you need internationalization, support the [`Accept-Language`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.5) HTTP header to provide a description according to the desired language.